# Python embedding

Tags: python, gcc, embed

I would like to have a single big binary which embeds Python interpreter and a small script - I'm totally new to this whole static linking, configure & make and GCC et al. Please, could someone describe to me the basic steps in building such executable?

I'm on MacOS 10.6, I downloaded Python 3.3 beta. Then, I created "test.c":

```
#include <Python.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Py_Initialize();
  PyRun_SimpleString("from time import time,ctime\n"
                     "print('Today is', ctime(time()))\n");
  Py_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

Now, in a folder, I have both "Python-3.3.0b1" folder and "test.c" file.

I typed:

```
gcc -I ./Python-3.3.0b1 -o test test.c
```

but I got lots of "include" error.

But I'm not even sure if this is the right way to proceed..? Should I first somehow build just Python and then "link" it with "test.c"?

Btw., if Python gets released do they use the same procedure of "./configure" and "make"? Do they use some special options or am I able to build very similar (the same) Python executable as the one provided from python.org?

Also, I tried this "./configure" and "make" and it made a folder called "build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.3" with lots of *.so files (?) but there is nothing called "python" or similar...?

Comment: Why are you using a beta version of python? Besides that, even if you statically link python into your application you'll still need all the stdlib stuff which is python code and thus cannot be simply linked into your binary.

Comment: I don't really care about the beta - I just read that the embedding technique changed slightly from v2 to v3.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that gcc doesn't know enough about your Python installation and isn't linking all the headers properly. You need to get that information from `distutils` and try and figure out how to get that information into gcc. This is explained better in the [Linking Requirements](http://docs.python.org/extending/embedding.html#linking-requirements) of the Embedding section of the Python documentation.

But there's an easier way. There is a script called `pymkfile.py` that will create a `make` file that includes all the information you need. See Section 4 of [this tutorial](https://www6.software.ibm.com/developerworks/education/l-pythonscript/l-pythonscript-ltr.pdf).

From Section 4, a *very* similar example to what you're trying to do:

> The simplest method of embedding Python code is to use the
>   PyRun_SimpleString() function. This function sends a single line of code to the
>   interpreter. Because the interpreter is persistent, it's like typing the individual lines in an interactive Python session, which means that you can execute new lines to the
>   interpreter by calling PyRun_SimpleString with each line of code. For example, the
>   following code runs a simple Python program to split and reassemble a string:

```
#include <Python.h>
int main()
{
printf("String execution\n");
Py_Initialize();
PyRun_SimpleString("import string");
PyRun_SimpleString("words = string.split('rod jane freddy')");
PyRun_SimpleString("print string.join(words,', ')");
Py_Finalize();
return 0;
}
```

> You can see that the basic structure is simple. You have the initialize and finalize
>   steps, and embedded between are the calls to the Python interpreter. To compile the
>   program, copy the code and save it to a file called pystring.c. First, use the script to
>   build a suitable Makefile:

```
$ pymkfile.py pystring > Makefile
```

> Now, run `make` to actually build the code. After the final application has been created,
>   run the application to see the results:

```
$ ./pystring

String execution
rod, jane, freddy
```

> You've just executed a simple bit of Python code by using a C wrapper. You could use
>   the same basic technique to perform many different tasks that use Python embedded
>   in an application. The only obvious limitation is that, in essence, the two components
>   are separate. There's no communication between the embedded Python interpreter
>   and the host C application.
>
> So, you gave the interpreter some code and it executed and printed it out; note how
>   you didn't have to take the output from the interpreter, then print it: The interpreter sent the information directly to the standard output.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't quite follow. 1.) I don't have "Python installation" - well, MacOS has Python but I try to use the source files I just downloaded. 2.) "This is an issue when the application is linked to the static runtime library (libpython.a) and needs to load dynamic extensions (implemented as .so files)." Do I need *.a or *.so? Is it possible to use just the source files? Sorry, I', very new to all this.

Comment: You do have a Python installation that is included with MacOS and your C program needs to be linked to files that are included in that installation in order to execute the embedded Python code. Since you aren't telling gcc where those files are, you get linker (include) errors. It is possible to manually include the source files but it's a pain in the ass. Instead use the script from the tutorial I linked. Then, to properly link your application to your Python install, it should be two simple commands, 1) `./pymkfile.py myCapp >Makefile` which will create the make file followed by 2) `make`

Comment: A bit more about `make`: http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_16.html

Comment: I don't want to use the files in MacOS - I would like to build Python files myself (from the sources I downloaded) and link my C program against those. Is that possible?

Comment: You mean you want to write your own Python code and run it from your C program? Yes that's possible. But your C program still needs to know how to interpret the Python code. In order to do that, it needs to link to the Python interpreter installed on your machine.

Comment: I want to write my own Python code (1) and my C code (2). Then I download Python 3.3 source (my MacOS has 2.6). I want to build (3) myself, put (1) into (2) (like in the example above), compile it, and link against (3). And I want just one huge binary which says "rod, jane, freddy". My questions are: how to build (3) so that I can link (2) against it? Do I need to build (3) separately to (2) or is it possible to do it in just one step?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13121/discussion-between-embedded-kyle-and-ecir-hana)

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using py2app? If you are only interested in shipping a script and not writing C code, it could fit your needs better.

http://svn.pythonmac.org/py2app/py2app/trunk/doc/index.html

Comment: Thank you, I know about py2app. What I try to achieve however is to learn how this embedding and compiling works, especially for Python and I would like to try to write a bit of C.

Answer (score 1):

> Also, I tried this "./configure" and "make" and it made a folder
>   called "build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.3" with lots of *.so files (?)
>   but there is nothing called "python" or similar...?

The `.so` files are object files. The python executable is only produced AFTER you call `make install`, so the three steps:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

That last step usually involves `sudo`

**Make sure that you are not replacing your system Python.** Not a good idea.

If you are on OS X, the usual method is to link with the OS X Python system framework. This 'looks' like embedded Python, but you are linking to the existing system Python. The system Python link target is `libpython.dylib` in `/usr/lib`

If you are not adverse to using Xcode, just Google 'embedded Python OS X' and find a good tutorial.

I used [THIS](http://www.ragestorm.net/tutorial?id=21) tutorial first time I did it.